# Android: Save a video to PC/Laptop while recording it

Tags: android, video, save

I have an interesting question and I couldn't find any related solutions.

I plan on recording extremely large videos in my app. Maybe even a few hours long. With high resolution video it's really difficult and annoying to constantly move the video to a PC/Laptop or external HDD as the phone runs out of space.

**My question**

Is it possible to save data directly to a PC/Laptop hard disk (through USB or any other means) while the video is being recorded?

Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May [this](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/peepers) or [this](http://www.codepool.biz/making-android-smart-phone-a-remote-ip-camera.html) help you, instead of recording app on phone broadcast it on computer directly and store there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem with IP based streaming in my case would be the large amount of data that would be consumed. And the PC/Laptop  might not have access to wifi or gprs.

Comment: hmmmmm so lets try some other things 

NOTE:Things i am going to written below may work may not just my idea

Record Video in 2 section 

Section one and section 2

and give some size to both(one have more and other should have less ) of them when when size gets full copy video from that section to system or OTP and use other section for that time and when frames send complete make you app reliable on section 2 which just have been copied and make section 1 to delete data and thing goes on 

i dont know it actually work or not but give a try by this you can use any OTP device for it

Comment: sorry my mean OTG*

Comment: This doesn't directly answer my question but I did end up using an OTG in the end, so I'm going to accept this answer. Cheers